# Evitar acumulação em uma string ao clicar repetidas vezes em um botão

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código que funciona da seguinte forma:

Ao clicar no botão retorna uma string `aaaa,bbbbb` que são os values dos inputs.

Clicando pela segunda vez retorna `aaaa,bbbbb,aaaa,bbbbb` e assim sucessivamente.

A pergunta: como retornar sempre `aaaa,bbbbb` independentemente de quantos cliques sejam dados

```js
var strTotal2 ="";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bsubmit").click(function(){
        $("input[class^='outro-form-control']").each(function(){
            var str2 = ($(this).val());
            strTotal2 = strTotal2+","+str2;
        });
        myString2 = strTotal2.substring(1);
        console.log(myString2);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="sheets" name="sheets" class="contact-form row" method="post" action="c_form/envia.php" onsubmit="return false">
<input id="nome" name="nome" value="aaaa" class="outro-form-control" placeholder="Insira seu nome">
<input id="nation" name="email" value="bbbbb"  class="outro-form-control">
<button type="submit" id="bsubmit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Enviar</button>
<form>
```

Comment: `var strTotal2 ="";` tem de estar dentro do `submit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toda a pergunta merece uma resposta e vai ser a do comentário do Isac.

var strTotal2 =""; tem de estar dentro do submit.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bsubmit").click(function(){
        var strTotal2 ="";
        $("input[class^='outro-form-control']").each(function(){
            var str2 = ($(this).val());
            strTotal2 = strTotal2+","+str2;
        });
        myString2 = strTotal2.substring(1);
        console.log(myString2);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sheets" name="sheets" class="contact-form row" method="post" action="c_form/envia.php" onsubmit="return false">
<input id="nome" name="nome" value="aaaa" class="outro-form-control" placeholder="Insira seu nome">
<input id="nation" name="email" value="bbbbb"  class="outro-form-control">
<button type="submit" id="bsubmit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Enviar</button>
<form>
```